# Can you identify this yellow crane?

Tags: technic, set-identification

Can you identify this one?

It's part of a series of models I had as a kid that I want to take apart for my own kids now, and I'm looking for the original instructions.

[image: yellow crane]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like it is this [Universal Set with Flex System](http://brickset.com/sets/8074-1/Universal-Set-with-Flex-System). Looks like the [instructions](http://www.bricklink.com/search.asp?itemID=14404) can be had fairly cheaply.

Comment: Set 8074 confirmed. Inventory and building instructions available here: http://peeron.com/inv/sets/8074-1

Answer (score 1):

Don't pay for instructions until you check this site: http://lego.brickinstructions.com

They have a lot of PDF files of instructions listed for free.

Comment: Thanks. I’ve always used http://bricks.argz.com to find all the instructions I needed as PDFs.